# Mixin vs Ring Size

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

Historically, many SE tags have been inspired from Monero source code (see [monero-wallet-cli](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monero-wallet-cli), [monero-wallet-gui](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monero-wallet-gui), [txpool](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/txpool) and other examples).

I followed the [conversation](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/5pmz3f/maybe_a_good_idea_to_rename_mixin_in_the_code_to/) related to this [pull request](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-core/pull/430) on Reddit and similarly would like to rename [mixin](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mixin) to ring size [ring-size](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ring-size) on Stack Exchange.

The [pull request](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-core/pull/430) referenced above only encompasses a visual change in the GUI aimed at making Monero terminology easier to understand for those that may misinterpret the meaning of [mixin](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mixin).

Before proposing a more drastic pull request removing [mixin](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mixin) from all Monero source code why not test [ring-size](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ring-size) on Stack Exchange first to see how it is received?

I prefer [ring-size](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ring-size) but also [approved](https://monero.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=newest&filter=all) a [decoys](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decoys) and [possible-signers](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/possible-signers) synonym based on [community feedback](https://np.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/5qmnac/mixin_vs_ring_size_please_share_your_opinions/dd0gv1m/).

I [created](https://monero.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=newest&filter=all) a [mixin](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mixin) synonym for [ring-size](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ring-size). Currently both tags still exist. Now that we have reached broad consensus I think it is safe to move forward and merge the tags.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was originally thinking that 'decoys' is a good term, but later changed my mind due to some discussion on that reddit thread.

In my opinion, we need to kill off the term 'mixin' as soon as possible because it immediately causes newcomers to make wrong assumpions as to what it stands for and it could become a bigger burden than it already is.

On another note, there was an opinion that flashing the option (in the GUI software) to set the ring size makes more problems then it solves and I tend to agree with this. Your 'basic' user doesn't need to touch the default parameter so better hide it under andvanced options for those who already understand what it means. From this point of view, the term doesn't have to be self-explanatory and 'ring size' would make the interested person look it up and learn about it, while the ordinary user would just ignore it and continue to happily transact with default options, which is good enough.

Considerig the above, I'm voting for 'ring size'

Comment: My vote is also for ring size. I agree with you than a "basic" user should be left with the default ring size parameter and not pressed to select unnecessary options

Comment: I vote for ''ring size'' as well.

Comment: +1 for "ring size"

Comment: + 1 ring size. Agree with comment that the mixin term should be killed off ASAP

Comment: "possible-signers" is my next favorite suggestion based on this comment: https://np.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/5qmnac/mixin_vs_ring_size_please_share_your_opinions/dd0l63x/

Comment: Ring size is getting a lot of support so approving the synonym seems appropriate. Any thoughts about when we should merge the old mixin tags (replacing them with ring size)? Should we do it now or after the GUI language is changed (pull request pending)?

Comment: ya ring size +1

Comment: I agree, though I don't even understand what 'Mixin' is supposed to mean. I'm assuming its referring to "mixing in" in your coins with coins from other transactions/addresses, but it's not immediately clear to me. And as others have mentioned there are connotations to tumbling. Ring size is a much clearer term and will be easier to pin down with a clear definition, particularly as ring sizes increase or decrease.

Answer (score 3):

Are there technical reasons for `mixin` being inaccurate, besides that the casual observer might think it refers to active mixing from other bitcoin obfuscation techniques?

My personal opinion is that `mixin` makes sense and it doesn't bother me, but I'm not going to wage war if the majority disagrees with me.

For example:

> In object-oriented programming languages, a mixin is a class that
>   contains methods for use by other classes without having to be the
>   parent class of those other classes.

Likewise, in Monero the `mixin` count is the amount of other signatures (in addition to yours) included in the ring signature that authorizes your transaction.

Comment: Most comments I have seen have focused on mixin being confused with active mixing by beginners and potential negative attention that comes with that. Both "mixin" and "ring size" are just fine from a technical point of view.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be broad consensus here and on reddit. Everyone that's not aware of this recent debate will keep using the mixin tag out of habit, so I don't think usage of the mixin tag is a good measurement of consensus for the change. At the very best it can help measure user awareness of the debate.

My impression is that the devs are already planning on making the change, but they want to make sure the entire community is behind them before it's implemented.In case anyone disagrees with the change, we would want them to voice their disagreement here - and sooner rather than later.

I therefore think there's also a debate to be had in regards to when it's okay to remove the mixin tag.

Comment: I agree with you that it looks like we have broad consensus