# Ringsize or ring-size

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

Following [this discussion](https://monero.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160/mixin-vs-ring-size) [mixin](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mixin) was changed to [ring-size](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ring-size)

Should we change [ring-size](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ring-size) to [ringsize](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ringsize) based on [this GitHub pull request](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-core/pull/485)?

Should ring size be one [ringsize](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ringsize) or two [ring-size](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ring-size) words on Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

+1 for ringsize as a single word, with the main argument being that it doesn't need translation and can be used "as is" in any language (as discussed via other channels)

Answer (score 3):

Since your post that GUI pull request has been [merged](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-core/pull/485).

I will wait for more feedback on this before taking action. Since we already have a [synonym](https://monero.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) in place, it would only take seconds to swap all current [ring-size](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ring-size) tags with [ringsize](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ringsize)

**Edit: Hearing no objections, the tag swap is now complete.**